# Recommended readings for VaR

Tags: books

I am new to finance.I was trying to learn VaR.

Can someone please suggest me some good readings/book to know about VaR from the basics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AlRacoon's answer to this question might be helpful: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37417

Comment: Agreed with the comment above. Jorion's book: *Value at Risk: The New Benchmark for Managing Financial Risk* is a very good reference on the topic

Answer (score 4):

Jorion's book on VAR is a good introduction.

Also, if you search this community, there are some very good posts for practical implementation of VAR.

For example, in this question, there is a very good step by step description of how to calculate Monte Carlo VAR:

[Is there a step-by-step guide for calculating portfolio VaR using monte carlo simulations](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12592/is-there-a-step-by-step-guide-for-calculating-portfolio-var-using-monte-carlo-si/12595#12595)

Answer (score 2):

*Risk management and financial institutions*, by John C. Hull, is a classical exposition of the foundations of risk management, including VaR calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Professor Carol Alexander, "Market Risk Analysis", esp. "Volume IV: Value at Risk Models"